# Place a character as background in a div

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I want to create the following layout:

```
+----------------------------------+
|               TITLE              |
|                                  |
|                 +                |
|                                  |
|            (drop here)           |
+----------------------------------+
```

using the following HTML:

```
<div class="drop-box">
  <p>TITLE</p>
  <p>(drop here)</p>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.drop-box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.drop-box:before {
  content: "+";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
  display: block;
}
```

Problem is that the text is now placed below the box with the '+' inside. How can I get the text to be placed inside the box. I've tried to use `position: relative` for the `p` tags but that doesn't work.

I've created a pen for this here: http://codepen.io/kdbruin/pen/ryMjgb

Comment: Either position the pseudo element absolutely - or just insert the generated content after/before the first/second paragraph element (instead on the container.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set a line-height on the paragraps and set absolute position on the cross, like this:

```css
.drop-box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
}
.drop-box p{
  line-height:50px;
}
.drop-box:before {
  content: "+";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 150px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="drop-box">
  <p>TITLE</p>
  <p>(drop here)</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Another clean solution. Thanks for the insights.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Flexbox`, you just need to set `justify-content: space-between` and `flex-direction: column` on parent element, and then change order of pseudo-element and last p element.

```css
.drop-box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.drop-box:before {
  content: "+";
  font-size: 3em;
  order: 1;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
.drop-box p:last-child {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="drop-box">
  <p>TITLE</p>
  <p>(drop here)</p>
</div>
```

You could also use `position: absolute` on pseudo-element to remove it from elements flow and center it with `transform: translate()`

```css
.drop-box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
.drop-box:before {
  content: "+";
  font-size: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
p:last-child {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="drop-box">
  <p>TITLE</p>
  <p>(drop here)</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Love the second solution you provide here. The use of the `order` in the first is a bit more "obscure" compared to the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Insert the "+" after p tag

```css
.drop-box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.drop-box p:first-of-type:after {
  content: "+";
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin: 16px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="drop-box">
  <p>TITLE</p>
  <p>(drop here)</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yet another great solution to the problem. However, as I commented on @julien-van-der-kluft answer, I would like to keep the background character attached to the drop-box instead of the p tag as there are a few situations where only a single line of text is present.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of generating content on your `.drop-box` container, you can do it directly on the second paragraph:

```
.drop-box p:nth-child(2)::before {
  content: "+";
  display: block;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Of course, it will probably be easier and cleaner to apply class to your paragraph:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="drop-box">
  <p>TITLE</p>
  <p class="has-plus-before">(drop here)</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.has-plus-before {
  content: "+";
  display: block;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

Then for keep a clean vertical alignement, i suggest to use some flexbox properties on your container:

```
.drop-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Take a look to this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/julienvanderkluft/1mxwep20/

Comment: Another great solution to the problem. However, I would like to keep the background character attached to the `drop-box` instead of the `p` tag as there are a few situations where only a single line of text is present.

Answer (score 1):

Use abolute position on the p tags, with according top/bottom/left parameters and z-index -1 (and add `position: relative;` to `.drop-box`for the absolute positioning to work):

```css
.drop-box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.drop-box:before {
  content: "+";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
  display: block;
}

.drop-box > p {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
.drop-box > p:first-child {
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.drop-box > p:nth-child(2) {
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="drop-box">
  <p>TITLE</p>
  <p>(drop here)</p>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqEqmg

Comment: I really like this answer. I can use additional classes on the `div.drop-box` to select other background characters. Also, this would allow for various sizes of the background character.

Answer (score 0):

Here is easier way:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="drop-box">
  <p>TITLE</p>
  <p>+</p>
  <p>(drop here)</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.drop-box {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: This will work (using some flexbox magic to get it centered properly) but I would like to detach the icon font (used for the '+') from the content so it is more flexible when using different classes for different background characters.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give your `drop-box` container a fixed height.
There are many ways to center align content with CSS. In my opinion the best way is to use `flex-box`. Very easy to implement and very flexible.

HTML

```
<div class="drop-box">Title<br>+<br>(drop here)</div>
```

CSS

```
.drop-box {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 150px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I would like the background character to be independent of the content so this solution doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

As your title suggested, why won't draw `+` as background on parent with `linear-gradient()`?

```css
.drop-box {
  background-image: linear-gradient(black, black),
                    linear-gradient(black, black);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 30px 2px, 2px 30px;
  background-position: center center;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="drop-box">
  <p>TITLE</p>
  <p>(drop here)</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to use an icon font here as the background character changes based on certain conditions. Using your method is not an option in this case.

Comment: @KeesdeBruin Ok, np. But I'll leave my answer here because it may be helpful for some other person looking to draw `+` icon.